# How to add labels in panda dataframe columns with else condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with a column like this:

```
POLITICS          
BUSINESS 
TRAVEL         
SPORTS
....
DIVORCE
ARTS
WELLNESS
CRIME
```

e.g

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['CRIME', 10], ['BUSINESS', 15], ['SPORTS', 12],  ['TRAVEL', 2], ['WELLNESS', 3], ['ARTS', 25]]
  

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['category', 'no'])
df
```

I want to add a column 'label' and map four categories to labels like so

```
label_dict = {'CRIME':1, 'BUSINESS':2, 'SPORTS':3  'ARTS':4}
```

and then all of the remaining categories should be labeled as 5.
I have tried this and am getting a KeyError: 'label'.

```
df['label'] = df['category'].apply( lambda x : label_dict[x] if x in label_dict.keys() else 5)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you make an example of the input and output dataframe please?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. With your last edit, your code does not raise any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['label'] = df['category'].map(label_dict).fillna(5).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
   category  no  label
0     CRIME  10      1
1  BUSINESS  15      2
2    SPORTS  12      3
3    TRAVEL   2      5
4  WELLNESS   3      5
5      ARTS  25      4
```

Or with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['label'] = df['category'].replace(label_dict | {'.*': 5}, regex=True)
```

Or suggested by @mozway:

```
df['label'] = df['category'].map(lambda x: label_dict.get(x, 5))
```

Comment: `df['label'] = df['category'].map(lambda x: label_dict.get(x, 5))` would probably be more efficient